# How can I assign 'g-recaptcha-response' to a variable? With 'g-recaptcha-response' being a parameter inside $request->validate([])

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha, laravel-5.5, contact-form

> So what i want is to put 'g-recaptcha-response' in a variable to be able to use it in my condition to verify recaptcha but I haven't been able to do this. Is there any way to only use recaptcha field from the array inside validate() because my code as it is, redirects me back to homepage. It goes straight to else statement.

```
 public function contactanospost(Request $request){     
         $request->validate([                       
           'nombre' => 'required|distinct',
           'telefono'=> 'required|telefono',
            'correo' => 'required|email',
           'mensaje' => 'required',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',

         ]);
         if(POST['g-recaptcha-response']){             /*here I am trying to 
                                                   check with a condition if recaptch was really validated once the form is submitted */
           $token= POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
          $client = new Client();
          $response = $client->post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [

          'form_params' => array('secret' => 'mycaptchakey',
          'response'=> $token                       /*Checking with google parameters for recaptcha if the user was indeed verified */
        )
      ]);                                     
      $resultados = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents()); //decode with json
      if($resultados->success){ /*if this was a success then return a page with parameters from google recaptcha such as: secret, response, remote ip.*/
        dd($resultados); /*show the results from verified user and that recaptcha is working*/

   $contactanos = Contactanos::create($request->all());/* and create all fields for model Contactanos*/
   Mail::to('some@mail')->send(new enviacorreo($contactanos)); /* since it is a contact form then send all the information to some mail*/

     \Session::flash('flash_message','Tu mensaje ha sido enviado!'); /* send a message with "email delivered" verification*/
      return redirect()->back();
      }
      else{
        \Session::flash('flash_message','Robot');
        return redirect('/');
      }


         }
         else{
           return redirect('/');
         }









 }
```

> I'm now able to access request properties using input() what got me confused were my if statements. The real problem is that after:

```
$resultados = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

> next if statement is not getting the expected success but instead it goes straight to else with robot message:

```
 else{
    \Session::flash('flash_message','Robot');
    return redirect('/');
  }
```

Comment: Can't you use $request->input('g-recaptcha-response')?

Comment: I tried it but didn't work either.

Comment: Then don't use $request->validate, create a new Validate instance as I described in my answer below. Check: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: Let me see what i can do then with eveything you just showed me. But i seems weird that it is not accepting $request->input('g-recaptcha-response')

Comment: Have you attempted $request->get('g-recaptcha-response')?

Comment: Yes i just tried it with get and it didn't work either. It goes straight to else statement.

Comment: It works with input as you said @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin but as i explain in my edit, the problem now is that json decode is not returning success and that's why it goes straight to else statement with robot message. Any thoughts about it?

Comment: use `dd()` on the lines you suspect to debug or use `logger()` then inspect exactly where things are going wrong. I also suspect the possibility that using `$request->validate()` might be the cause. I think this question might be leaving its original scope but you need to debug line by lines to find out where things are. Also check the content of the response of the request.

Comment: Also you don't need the if condition to check if `g-captcha...` exists since the validator already did that for you. Remove it and leave the code without any redirection the add your desired code step by step and test again.

Comment: Great insight. I’ll start going line by line then to see where the problem might be and I’ll change my code with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can access all the properties of the request from the `$request` object by calling e.g, `$request->input('g-recaptcha-response')` This is the basic of [Accessing the request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#accessing-the-request) if you have read through the documentation.

I can lend you a snippet to do this perhaps it will help you rethink how you're validating the captcha:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
....


    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|min:2',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
        'subject' => 'sometimes|required|min:3',
        'message' => 'required|min:3',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'sometimes|required'
    ], [
        'g-recaptcha-response.*' => 'Please verify that you are not a robot'
    ]);

    if ($v->fails()) {
        return [
            'success' => 'no',
            'data' => $v->errors()->first()
        ];
    }

    if ($request->get('g-recaptcha-response')) {
        $verify_form = [
            'secret'    => env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET', 'default'), //better to save in config though
            'response'  => $request->get('g-recaptcha-response')
        ];

        $client = new Client();
        $verify_serial = '?'.http_build_query($verify_form);

        $response = $client->post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'.$verify_serial);
        $arrayed_response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        if(!$arrayed_response['success']){
            Log::notice('There is something wrong with the verification of recaptcha: ',$arrayed_response );
            return [
                'success' => 'no',
                'data' => 'Something went wrong in verification process',
            ];
        }
    }
```

The idea is that, you build the secret and response body and use that to request validation check from Google just as you have done but building the query as query parameters directly to the url.

> PS: you don't have to return the snippet :)